# User/Group rights and premission in tridion

Tags: tridion

We have created a group in the Group Management section of Administration and assigned few of the publications to it.

Now through User Management section once we open a user entry and try to Add this group in the "Member of" tab, the group is not getting added. All the existing default tridion groups are getting added properly.

Please suggest.

Comment: What behavior are you experiencing when not getting added? Do you select the group, save changes, and the changes are not persisted? Or you can't find the newly created group when trying to add the user to the group?

Comment: There was some problem in the naming of the group which had an '&'. Once removed the group is now getting added. So it's working now.

Comment: Interesting point and thanks for following up. I see the same in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1. From the user screen, after selecting a group with an ampersand (&) in its name with `Add` > (click) `Select`, the pop-up closes and no group shows in the 'Member of' tab.

Comment: Looking at these comments, there is some information here that would be good to share. Could you please update the question so that it makes sense? Then perhaps it can be re-opened.

Comment: Is it possible to re-open and also move? It's more of a super user or maybe webmaster type question. Btw, I described the scenario to SDL Support (ticket 154824), I'm guessing the expected behavior should be to either prevent ampersands or allow adding the group.

Comment: I have just experienced the same problem. If there is an ampersand in the Group name, then it does not get added to the User. This is a real question! @frank-van-puffelen - Can we re-open this please?